# How to enter filesystem on docker container after computer crash?

Tags: docker

I had a running Docker container on a computer.

The computer crashed due to a power failure. The disk started up right etc, and now I want to go somehow go to the container and "salvage" the data from there. I know the container ID.

I can see the diffs in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` ; however, I need the whole filesystem as it was during the crash, if possible.

In `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt`, I don't see a thing.

When I tried to run another docker with `--with-volumes (ID)`, I see nothing there.

How to get to the actual data, as they were during the crash?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it's "the right way", but this helped me.

```
docker commit (ID of the crashed container)
```

This creates a new image out of the crashed container and gives me its ID. Now I just have to run the new image...

```
docker run -ti (ID of the new image)
```

and I can now safely salvage the data.

Comment: To identify the crashed container: `$ docker container ls --all`, can also just `$ docker start -ai <crashed container ID>`

Answer (score 0):

Posting this here as well for easy of googling. Originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813486/exploring-docker-containers-file-system/42368711#42368711).

The easiest way I've found for copying from a non-functional container is docker cp.

```
docker cp <container-name>:<path/inside/container> <path/on/host/>
```

Thanks to docker cp ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)) you can copy directly from the container as it was any other part of your filesystem. For example, recovering all files inside a container:

```
mkdir /tmp/container_temp
docker cp example_container:/ /tmp/container_temp/
```

Note that you don't need to specify that you want to copy recursively.